# django-ckeditor files upload other than image

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Iam using django-ckeditor.

Iam uploading image files and .swf files in image and flash upload icons. But when i upload files other than these, Iam getting error as "cannot identify image file". For swf files , thumbnail is not creating and dummy image is showing without any url.

My views in ckeditor as :
@csrf_exempt

```
def upload(request):
    upload = request.FILES['upload']
    upload_ext = os.path.splitext(upload.name)[1]
    upload_filename = get_upload_filename(upload.name, request.user)
    out = open(upload_filename, 'wb+')
    for chunk in upload.chunks():
        out.write(chunk)
    out.close()
    if upload_ext != ".swf": 
        create_thumbnail(upload_filename)
    url = get_media_url(upload_filename)
    url = url.replace("\\", "/")
    return HttpResponse("""
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(%s, '%s');
    </script>""" % (request.GET['CKEditorFuncNum'], url))
```

thumbnail,

```
def create_thumbnail(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        image = image.convert('RGB')
   imagefit = ImageOps.fit(image, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imagefit.save(get_thumb_filename(filename))
```

Anyone help me to solve this issue..

Comment: What are all the other file types do you upload?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, only image files can have thumbnails. All other types should have default thumbnails based on the their types(may be icon image). In your code, the logic should

```
if upload_ext in [".jpg", ".png",]:
    create_thumbnail(filename)
else:
    create_default_thumbnail(upload_ext) // for .swf, .doc etc
```